# SSH parameter to ignore .bashrc script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a server which executes this line in `.bashrc` when it starts: `/bin/watch ~/checker.bash`. Which, as expected, watches that command upon server start.

I also have a client which logs into that machine, but I do not want the client's sessions to execute the same command from the `.bashrc`.

I have looked at `AcceptEnv` for passing env vars, though it requires configuration of the server, which I want to avoid.

I also don't want to have two different user accounts for different `.bashrc`s.

Is there another angle to approach this from?

Comment: why don't you want two different accounts? all "clients" (which seem to be an unrelated 3rd parties) should be isolated (also from yourself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could activate parts of your `.bashrc` only if it is not invoked via `ssh`.

e.g. something like:

```
# within an SSH-session, ${SSH_TTY} will be set
if [ "x${SSH_TTY}" = "x" ]; then
  /bin/watch ~/checker.bash
fi
```

Answer (score 22):

Two ways:

Don't use bash for this session, try dash (or /bin/sh):

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 /bin/dash
```

Use bash with command options to disable processing startup files:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 "bash --noprofile --norc"
```

Comment: The 2nd method just hangs for me.

Comment: The second method works perfectly for me.  You don't see a prompt since PS1 isn't set, which is a side effect of performing as requested.

Comment: both just hang for me

Comment: @AdityaMittal Both will appear to hang if you are invoking an interactive session because there is no PS1 prompt.  Try typing 'ls /'

Comment: this doesnt work for me, because the .bashrc needs to allow it first, and if it has something that runs first that is kicking you off, then you never get past that point.

Comment: Yep, mine doesn't work either. I ended up deleting the bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute the line /bin/watch .... with

```
 if ps ax | grep /bin/watch | grep -v grep  > /dev/null 2>&1
 then
    echo "Nothing to do"
 else
    /bin/watch ~/checker.bash
 fi
```

or some such thing.